# How to add shape keys to high poly model?

Tags: sculpting, shape-keys, multiresolution

I'm trying to add muscles shape key to my high poly character (~1 million faces). I'm using a *Multires* modifier to unsubdivide the mesh to ~65000 faces, but with sculpt parameter=2 to get more details in sculpt mode.
[image: Multires parameters]
But when I've created muscles and changed to object mode, everything I did in sculpt mode disappears. And now I can't apply a *Multires* modifier because *"Modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys"*. Is there a right way to create shape keys in sculpt mode for high poly mesh?

I'm creating characters for my game, so I want to simulate the muscles growth. Like if I have strength 1 my character doesn't have muscles, if I have strength 100 my character is getting 6 pack abs, for example. The easy way to achieve it in Unreal Engine 4 is to use morph targets - shape keys in Blender. In the beginning, I just want to make muscles growth.

Comment: When you create a shapekey and switch back to Object mode you need to put the shapekey value at 1, otherwise you won't see it. For the modifier problem, I guess you need to apply your multires before creating shapekeys. But why do you need so many faces?

Comment: @moonboots "you need to put the shapekey value at 1, otherwise you won't see it" - i did it, nothing changed. "But why do you need so many faces?" - i just study now, so i trying to follow the pipeline: high poly sculpt, retopology, uv, bake, textures, rig, animations. Is it wrong?

Comment: Your base object should be low poly, it will make any modeling work (and also any animation) easy. Then if you want to sculpt details you can either give a Multiresolution modifier to your object, or duplicate the object and create a high-poly version (to make this high-poly either apply a Subdivision Surface modifier or use Dyntopo). Once you have your high-poly version, bake the details onto the low-poly version (if you've used Multires, don't apply it). Now you can work on shapekeys on the low-poly.

Comment: @moonboots sorry, I totally confused( My problem is that I have two high poly version: with muscles and without muscles. I'm trying to join this versions in one, using shape keys, but everything that I'm doing in sculpt mode is affecting only on basic mesh, so my shape keys are useless.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your goal and method, I hope someone will help

Comment: @Сергей the pipeline is correct. But why do you need 2 high-poly versions? Do you want to simulate muscle contractions? A sculpt with 1 million faces and shape keys is a bad idea. It increases the amount of data a lot. And not all modifiers work with shapekeys and get blocked. I've done this once when I was clueless and it broke my mesh and crashed blender.

Comment: @Blunder I'm creating characters for my game, so I want to simulate the muscles growth. Like if i have strength 1 my character don't have muscles, if i have strength 100 my character is getting 6 pack abs, for example. Easy way to achive it in unreal engine 4 is to use morph targets - shape keys in blender. Yes, I want to simulate muscle contractions but now I know too little in blender, so for beginning I just want to make muscles growth.

Comment: @moonboots thank you, I hope too.

Comment: Thanks for the context. Let's assume you can have a high-poly sculpt with shape keys for muscles. What's your workflow then? What is the advantage of it for the game model? Why do you need the high-poly shape keys? Wouldn't you create a low-poly base version of the character, and a muscle hero version and use these for the game?

Comment: @Blunder because in that case to provide smooth changing I need to create a lot of hero versions. In additional, I planned to make a lot of shape keys for legs (endurance), face (age, face animation), arms (power) etc... I can't create so much models. "Why do you need the high-poly shape keys?" - maybe, I don't need it, but I suppose I should do it in high poly to get better result in low poly, am I right?